# Is there any expression in English that express the assistance among members in a family?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ok, this is pretty popular in Asia but not in Western countries.

In Asia & especially in many traditional families, members in the families often help each other when 1 of the member got some difficulties in their life.

For example, in a family, a brother made some mistakes & now I owe a big money (maybe 50K USA). Now, the siblings in that family will support him so that he can pay off his debt.

So, **Is there any expression in English that express the assistance among members in a family?**

Comment: Certainly in most parts of the world family members tend to help each other.  I'm not thinking of a common English idiom for this, though, at least not one consistent with your description.  (There is *nepotism*, but that's viewed as a pejorative, meaning special treatment for family members in a business or government job.)

Comment: I think this is just called a family support network. And thus that person would be relying on their family support network to get through their difficulty. But that describes the people in it not the help they provide.  I don't know of any word specifically for "the assistance provided by close family members."

Comment: family solidarity?

Comment: [*"Blood is thicker than water"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_is_thicker_than_water)

Comment: In Mexican Spanish (which is pretty widely spoken in the US), the concept (with its own idea of the extended family) is called _compadrazco_ 'co-parenthood'. One tries to get as many compadres as possible, especially if they're important people; conversely, important people find status in the number of compadres they help support. Given the institutional corruption that's endemic to Mexico, compadrazco is the only support system that people trust. However, while it includes relatives, it is much broader in extent.

Comment: "We pulled together as a family"? [Irony/sarcasm] "I guess I couldn't wean myself from my family's chest"?

Comment: @Tom In French we would say, "Il faut 'se serrer les coudes,'" which means something along the lines of "we should stick/band together."

Comment: Although it did originate from a silly kids' movie, there is an expression that has entered popular culture:  "[Ohana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohana) means family.  Family means nobody gets left behind - or forgotten."

Comment: Family helps family. Although *[stick together](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/283863/166321)* is what I'd choose.

Answer (score 1):

Consider, ***stick together***.

> : be loyal to one another, esp. in times of trouble : the two families
>   stuck together throughout the war. [FD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stick+together)

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to find the right word/phrase for your context, but "***contribution from family (members)***" might be close.

[***Contribution***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contribution) means:

> A gift or payment to a common fund or collection: ‘the agency is
>   mainly financed from voluntary contributions’

If you owe USD50K and 5 members of your family gave you USD10K each, you can say:

> 5 members of my family "***contributed***" USD10K each to help me
>   repay the debt.

[***Contribute***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contribute) means:

> Give (something, especially money) in order to help achieve or provide
>   something:

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Answer (score 0):

My family is pretty **tight** (and we do happen to be from the Western hemisphere).

One of us was diagnosed with cancer, so the rest of us **came together** and each took our turns being chemo-buddies (you just go with them, and be there for moral support).

Why?

Because **they're family.**

*We are family*, is an expression in English (and a really good [song](https://www.google.com/search?q=We+are+family&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)) that means we *will* provide assistance, because it's an intrinsic responsibility and, according to my mom, **"your DUTY as a member of this family."**

'Family' are the ones who **will always be there for you**, no matter what (regardless of blood relation).

IMO, you might need to find the word that means *not this*, as (at least in mine) *family* already implies it. That's why we have words like *estranged* : (no longer close or affectionate to someone; alienated –G).

---

Beatles: **Come Together** Meaning –[lyricinterpretations.com](https://www.lyricinterpretations.com/beatles/come-together)

> "COME TOGETHER RIGHT NOW...OVER ME" refers to the message the Yogi delivered to the band as a group that would supposedly heal the growing rift and dissension between the four members of the band and unite them as a single cohesive unit once again.

---

If more than just your direct family members support you, i.e., friends, family, donations from strangers, etc., then it can be said that they all **came together as** (*if they were*) **a family**.

If your family isn't on the best of terms, like the Beatles were at one point, you might say: this is what **finally brought us together as a family**.

---

Do not confuse this with [Tough Love](https://www.google.com/search?q=Tough%20Love&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), which is an acceptable practice in my family, when it's appropriate; "requiring them to take responsibility for their actions."

Ironically, your family may *'come together'* in order to ensure the application of *'tough love'* from all parties (no cheating), with the intent to help them in the long run.

---

See also: [With a Little Help from My Friends](http://www.veoh.com/watch/v16039034KRFprghT)

Answer (score -1):

*'Patronage'* in a close approximation, but suggests too strongly that all relations centre on the *'patron'* rather than describing a system of family wide relationships.  Furthermore, *'patronage'* has evolved away from the sense of father (L. *pater*), in the direction of the related Latin word *patronus* meaning defender or champion.

There are effective words describing families, such as *kinship* and *familial*, but no readily apparent single words to describe the dynamics within them.  The word *familiarity* has gained another meaning entirely and lost its utility in this sense of connectedness.

The word *fraternal* suffers from an association with purely male connections (as sorority does on the other side of the gender divide) , while *tribal* or *tribalism* misses the mark.  *Clan* and *clannish* do better, but suggest insularity rather than the power network within the family group.

Returning to *patronage*, the *-age* element appears to be the key to giving the word patron the sense of a process or arrangement.  Applying the same suffix to that rare, but very precise word ***consanguinous*** (meaning of a related family) yields ***consanginage***, although we may have to settle for ***consanguineous* or *consanguinuity*** if we want to remain in the known world of words.

From the OED:

> consanguineous consanguineous, a.
>   (kɒnsæŋˈgwɪniːəs)
>   [f. L. consanguine-us of the same blood (f. con- + sanguis, sanguin- blood) + -ous.]
>   1. Of the same blood, related by blood, akin; of or pertaining to those so related.
>   *1601 Shakes. Twel. N. ii. iii. 82 Am not I consanguinious? Am I not of her blood: tilly vally. 1656 S. Holland Zara (1719) 89 Not like Aliens, but as having consanguineous Alliance. 1781 Mrs. Thrale in Mad. D'Arblay's Diary & Lett. II. 109 Of this consanguineous fondness I have had little experience myself. 1871 Darwin Desc. Man II. xxi. 403 A plan for ascertaining..whether or not consanguineous marriages are injurious to man.*